# Having trouble installing PubNub and using it with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pubnub

I've been trying to install pubnub on my mac and then use it in PyCharm. When I run the install command on terminal, it says that all the requirements are satisfied, leading me to believe it is installed on my machine. However, when I try to install it on PyCharm, it gives me the error that the packages are not found and I am unable to use it.

```
pip3 install pubnub==4.5.2
Requirement already satisfied: pubnub==4.5.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex>=3.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pubnub==4.5.2) (3.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pubnub==4.5.2) (2.23.0)
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual messages from your command line? Also, all versions of all things that matter. Cheers.

Comment: The first line is the command I put in, and the rest are some of what came up:pip3 install pubnub==4.5.2
Requirement already satisfied: pubnub==4.5.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex>=3.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pubnub==4.5.2) (3.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pubnub==4.5.2) (2.23.0)

Comment: Are you sure the Python installation which has the package is the same as the one you're using to execute the program?

Comment: That's my thinking on what's wrong, I haven't had a chance to check yet but I'm going to give it a try thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I consulted with the PubNub Engineering team. It seems to have more to do with PyCharm than PubNub, specifically. It is likely that your PyCharm is not using the same python environment as when you run from your terminal. Here are some links that should assist with getting everything configured the way you need it:

- [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)﻿
- [Create a virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)
- [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)﻿

Not implying to do all of the above, but read through all of them and decide what actions you may need to take based on your environment. For further issues, you may need to hit up a PyCharm forum.

If there is something specific to PubNub, you can send your inquiry with as much detail as possible to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com). But again, probably just environment configuration issues that you would have with any third party Python library, similar to PubNub.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem too after doing some more research. Thank you so much for your help!